# Can I query email messages sent by Email Alert feature?

Tags: email, email-alert, object

`SELECT COUNT() FROM EmailMessage` does not change after sending an email using the Email Alert feature. I compared it to emails sent from Apex, and created manually, from Case:

```
[Process Builder + Email Alert], before: Query Results - Total Rows: 165

[Process Builder + Email Alert], after: Query Results - Total Rows: 165

[Apex], before: Query Results - Total Rows: 165

[Apex], after: Query Results - Total Rows: 166

[Manually from Case], before: Query Results - Total Rows: 166

[Manually from Case], after: Query Results - Total Rows: 167
```

Is there any way to retrieve these messages out of database? Is it about another object - what's its name?

Comment: I can't give you a complete answer but the `EmailMessage` object is only used in enhanced email and email to case. I don't believe email alerts qualify. Some emails in Salesforce are stored as tasks so you can try to query that object and see if the alerts are saved but I am fairly confident they wont be there either. As of right now, I don't believe that alerts are stored but I've been wrong before.

Comment: Thanks @gNerb. I've read some stuff in [Learn about the 'Enhanced Email' and EmailMessage objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313606&type=1&mode=1) and [Considerations for Using Enhanced Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&type=5) and no info there sadly. I also checked ``Tasks`` but with no luck either - only emails counted in my question resulted in creating them.

Comment: I just did some searches through my WSDL which contains all standard objects and I searched for all instances of "alert" and "email" (boy is there a lot of email results) and couldn't find anything that seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @gNerb no other options found so far. I think that you can promote your comment to the answer - I'll vote it up and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmailMessage` object is only used in enhanced email and email to case. I don't believe email alerts qualify. Some emails in Salesforce are stored as tasks so you can try to query that object and see if the alerts are saved but I am fairly confident they wont be there either. As of right now, I don't believe that alerts are stored. Ive seen a few ideas on stack excahnge asking for the same thing with no results.

I did some searches through my WSDL which contains all standard objects and I searched for all instances of "alert" and "email" (boy is there a lot of email results) and couldn't find anything that seems to be what you are looking for.

The last option is resort to code to send the emails and store them in tasks or email alerts yourself.